# FileNotFoundError: No file found in working directory

Tags: python, pygame

```
 import pygame
 pygame.init()




goleft = [pygame.image.load('placeholder_walk_left_1.png'),
pygame.image.load('placeholder_walk_left_2.png')]


stand = [pygame.image.load('placeholder_stand_1.png'),
pygame.image.load('placeholder_stand_2.png')]


goright = [pygame.image.load('placeholder_walk_right_1.png'),
pygame.image.load('placeholder_walk_right_2.png')]
```

почему файлы которые находятся в той же папке не хотят грузиться?
(уже пробовал указать не только название файла, но и полный путь до него)
(код не полный)
почему то он выдает путь "'C:\Users\гнида" не смотря на то, что путь до файлов выглядит как "C:\Users\гнида\game"

Comment: Значит во время запускания кода вы и в самом деле находитесь именно в папке `C:\Users\гнида`

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо указать полное имя файла вместе с расширением, например, так

`'placeholder_walk_right_2.png'`

```
 import pygame
 pygame.init()

goleft = [pygame.image.load('placeholder_walk_left_1.png'),
pygame.image.load('placeholder_walk_left_2.png')]

stand = [pygame.image.load('placeholder_stand_1.png'),
pygame.image.load('placeholder_stand_2.png')]

goright = [pygame.image.load('placeholder_walk_right_1.png'),
pygame.image.load('placeholder_walk_right_2.png')]
```

Comment: а это я уже в вопросе ошибку допустил. расширение файлов я добавил, ничего не изменилось

Comment: @Гнида попробуйте переименовать в файлы в более короткое имя, например, ```pwl1.png``` ( и чтобы не было почерков в имени )